# inverse mouse wheel user action. scroll down = right in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a 100% height page, and I would like to add a bit of javascript so that when the user scrolls down, the site scrolls right/left, so that all mouse interaction is closed to just left and right? Is this possible with jquery without having a fixed point to scroll to and just the end of the page width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery mouse wheel plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/)

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (delta > 0) {
        self.scrollLeft(self.scrollLeft()-40);
    } else {
        self.scrollLeft(self.scrollLeft()+40);
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eng0t4h6/)**